# QVector<float> or float* - Qt memory management better than native C++?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, optimization, memory-management

Should I choose `float*` over `QVector` on a memory management point of few for a memory critical application, when initializing huge data structures?

In particular, I need to write into the structure in a loop with many iterations. The `operator[]` accessor for `QVector` does copy-on-write. Is it an argument more to use a `float*` and access its elements?

Comment: Benchmark it. An optimising compiler will make most things irrelevant anyway, so it's best to go for the clearest option unless it's demonstrably slower. Though of course, if you have a huge list of vectors, you may be better off using a matrix (both performance-wise and conceptually).

Comment: A vector is a just a pointer to an array anyway. The big difference will be the resizing of the array when you exceed capacity. Using a `float*` yourself, you explicitly limit and define the size of your array. If you know in advance the maximum size of the vector, you can manually change the capacity of it and enjoy the interface of the vector class without the drawback of resizing time.

Comment: is there an overhead of using QVector ?  i dont need the resize feature. I am using QVector and application is too memory consumming. bottleneck is allocation of the data structure

Comment: We need way more context to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use `QVector` or `std::vector`. Since `QVector` stores floats in a continous memory region it will perform nearly as fast as `float` array. Copy-on-write add checks, but I don't think it will be relevant, but in case it's important `std::vector` doesn't do COW.

Use `QVector`, benchark it. If it's too slow, only then try to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling memory allocation with the Windows PSAPI API, it was possible to experience that there is negligeable difference in memory consumption between QVector and float*.